# How can I copy three partitions of my disk with a specific beginning and ending using dd?

Tags: shell, partition, dd

Using the `fdisk -l` command I got the following answer:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    28266495    14132224   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2        28268544    28473343      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        28473344   132552703    52039680    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4   *   132556798   625141759   246292481    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       193996800   198092799     2048000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       234960896   625141759   195090432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       198094848   234950316    18427734+  83  Linux
/dev/sda8       132556800   183756018    25599609+  83  Linux
```

I'd like to copy the three first partitions of my disk in an image using the `dd` command. So I mounted an external hard drive, entered in its folder and typed:

```
# dd count=$((132552703-2048)) if=/dev/sda of=./newImage.image
```

But this command copied all the sda disk to my external hard drive instead of just copying until the end of the sda3 partition.

How can I use the `dd` to create an image that starts at the beginning of sda1 and finishes at the end of sda3?

Comment: try with  dd bs=2048 count=$(( (132552703-2048)/204)) *your other arg*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### first of all, here's how:

---

1. First do *almost* as you did before, but no subtraction - and add one to the count.

   ```sh
   dd  count=132552704 </dev/sda >img
   ```
2. Next print the partition table at a `sed` process which can screen out the ones which you're removing.

   - `sed` will write a `d`elete command to a second `fdisk` which has opened your *`img`* file for every partition from sda4 and on.

     ```sh
     fdisk -l img | sed -e'/sda4 /,$id' -e'g;$aw' | fdisk img
     ```
3. There is no 3. You're done.

---

#### secondly, here's why:

---

- A Partial Success...

  - I'm pretty sure your command *almost* worked, but I'm willing to bet that it worked better than you think.
  - I expect that when you say it *copied all of sda* you believe that because an `fdisk -l` of that image indicated all of the partitions were included within. Based on the `dd` command in your question, though, provided `/dev/sda`'s sector size is the fairly standard 512 bytes *(and therefore identical to `dd`'s default blocksize)* then you should have copied everything from byte 0 of `/dev/sda` only through to all but the last 2k sectors of `/dev/sda3`.
- About Sectors...

  - You can see below where the `fdisk` output reports on *Units*. That is the size of each *sector* that `fdisk` reports on. A disk *sector* **might** be 4096-bytes - if it is a very recently manufactured disk and handles the [*Advanced Format*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) sector-size - otherwise it is very rare to find a disk not partitioned on a standard logical 512-byte sector-size.
  - This is how [`fdisk`'s `man` page](http://man7.org/linux/manpages/man8/fdisk.8.html) puts it:
  - > *`-u`*, *`--units[=unit]`*
  - > > - When listing partition tables, show sizes in *sectors* or in *cylinders*. **The default is to show sizes in *sectors***. For backward compatibility, it is possible to use the option without the *unit* argument - then the default is used. Note that the optional unit argument cannot be separated from the *`-u`* option by a space, the correct form is for example *`-u=cylinders`*.
  - There's [more on this here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215533/52934).
- And something about `dd`, too...

  - `dd` **cannot** *silently lose data*. In fact, if a short read occurs, `dd` is [specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) to be *very* vocal about it:
  - > A partial input block is one for which `read()` returned less than the input block size. A partial output block is one that was written with fewer bytes than specified by the output block size...
  - > ...when there is ***at least one*** truncated block, the number of truncated blocks shall be written to standard error...
  - > > *`"%u truncated %s\n"`*, *`<number of truncated blocks>`*, *`"record[s]"`*
- Block i/o...

  - But anyway, that actually *can't* happen with block-device i/o. It's what makes a block-device a block-device - there's an extra layer *(sometimes several)* of buffered protection for block-devices as opposed to character devices. It is this distinction which enables POSIX to guarantee `lseek()` for files existing on block-devices - it's a very basic principle of blocked i/o.
- To sum up...

  - And so you have copied *all* of your device up to the point you specified, but the thing is, the *first* 2k sectors of `/dev/sda` will contain its *entire* partition table, and as such you would have copied said partition table to your image, and so an `fdisk -l` of your image would report for *all* partitions of `/dev/sda`, whether or not the data for those partitions actually resides within that image-file. You can, instead, of course, just `cat` the separate data partitions separately into separate image files if you like - but in that case you lose the partition table entirely. All you really have to do is delete the partitions which you did not copy, and make sure you copy *all* of those you do.

---

#### third, here's how I know:

---

- This will create an 4G *`./img`* file full of NULs.

  ```sh
  </dev/zero >./img \
  dd ibs=8k obs=8kx1b count=1kx1b
  ```

  ---

  ```
  524288+0 records in
  1024+0 records out
  4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB) copied, 3.53287 s, 1.2 GB/s
  ```
- This will partition *`./img`* to match your disk up to the first three partitions but on a 1/16th scale:

  ```sh
  (set "$((p=0))" 28266495     27 \
        28268544  28473343  2\\n7 \
        28473344 132552703  3\\n7
  while   [ "$#" -ge "$((p+=1))" ]
  do      printf "n\np\n$p\n%.0d\n%d\nt\n%b\n" \
                 "$(($1/16))" "$(($2/16))" "$3"
          shift 3
  done;   echo w
  )| fdisk ./img >/dev/null
  ```
- And so now we can look at it.

  ```sh
  fdisk -l ./img
  ```

  ---

  ```
  Disk ./img: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x5659b81c

  Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors   Size Id Type
  ./img1             2048 1766655 1764608 861.6M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
  ./img2          1766784 1779583   12800   6.3M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ./img3          1779584 8284543 6504960   3.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ```
- I'll also put some actual filesystems and files on the three partitions.

  ```sh
  sudo sh -c ' trap "$1" 0
      cd /tmp; mkdir -p mnt
      for p in "$(losetup --show -Pf "$0")p"*
      do    mkfs.vfat "$p"
            mount "$p" mnt
            echo  "my part# is ${p##*p}" \
                   >./mnt/"part${p##*p}"
            sync; umount mnt
      done' "$PWD/img" 'losetup -D'
  ```
- Here are the byte offsets for where it all wound up...

  ```sh
  grep -Ebao '(my[^0-9]*|PART)[123]' <./img
  ```

  ---

  ```
  2826272:PART1
  2830336:my part# is 1
  904606240:PART2
  904624640:my part# is 2
  917656608:PART3
  917660672:my part# is 3
  ```

But did you notice that `fdisk` was perfectly happy to report on the partitions' sizes before ever we formatted them with filesystems? This is because the partition table lies at the very head of the disk - it's only a layout and nothing more. None of the partitions need actually exist to be reported. They're only logically mapped out within the first 1M of `./img`. Watch:

- Let's try getting only the first two partitions off of `./img`...

  ```sh
  <./img >./img2 dd count=1779583
  ```

  ---

  ```
  1779583+0 records in
  1779583+0 records out
  911146496 bytes (911 MB) copied, 1.84985 s, 493 MB/s
  ```
- We'll `grep` it again...

  ```sh
  grep -Ebao '(my[^0-9]*|PART)[123]' <./img2
  ```

  ---

  ```
  2826272:PART1
  2830336:my part# is 1
  904606240:PART2
  904624640:my part# is 2
  ```
- And get an `fdisk` report...

  ```sh
  fdisk -l ./img2
  ```

  ---

  ```
  Disk ./img2: 869 MiB, 911146496 bytes, 1779583 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0xcbcab4d8

  Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors   Size Id Type
  ./img2p1           2048 1766655 1764608 861.6M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
  ./img2p2        1766784 1779583   12800   6.3M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ./img2p3        1779584 8284543 6504960   3.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ```

Now that is curious. `fdisk` still seems to believe there's a third partition extending as far out as 4G for a disk which it also seems to believe is only 869M in size!

- Probably we should remove that third partition from the partition table.

  ```sh
  printf %s\\n d 3 w |
  fdisk ./img2 >/dev/null
  ```
- And now lets see if we can mount the partitions we copied and if our files remain in tact...

  ```sh
  sudo sh -c ' trap "$1" 0
      cd /tmp; mkdir -p mnt
      for p in "$(losetup --show -Pf "$0")p"*
      do    mount "$p" mnt
            grep . /dev/null ./mnt/*
            umount mnt
      done' "$PWD/img2" 'losetup -D'
  ```

  ---

  ```
  ./mnt/part1:my part# is 1
  ./mnt/part2:my part# is 2
  ```

Apparently it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible because dd is only direct 1 input to 1 output --the restoration would be damage because you merged 3 partitions in one and this isn't a backup and dd is only for identical copies.

Your answer would be possible:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/hdadisk1.img; 
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=~/hdadisk2.img
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=~/hdadisk3.img
```

(In a script if you want) and finally, you can to create an image with the hdadisk{1,3,3}.img although is a better practice you save these images in a partition for backups.

Answer (score 0):

`dd count=$((132552703-2048))` copies 132552703-2048 blocks of 512 bytes from the beginning of the input. The block size in `fdisk` is 1 kB = 1024 bytes. So you have three problems:

- You specified a size that's half what you wanted.
- You didn't indicate that you wanted to start the copy at an offset.
- Your subtraction has a fencepost error: it misses the last block — the number of blocks is (end block offset) - (start block offset) + 1.

So you can do that copy with

```
dd bs=1k skip=2048 count=$((132552703-2048+1)) if=/dev/sda of=./newImage.image
```

I think this will work — [`dd` can silently lose data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial), but I think that 1kB blocks on a block device or regular file on Linux is fine. But [it's slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd).

The most straightforward way to copy a single partition would be to just copy it.

```
cat /dev/sda1 >sda1.image
cat /dev/sda2 >sda2.image
cat /dev/sda3 >sda3.image
```

It would be better to copy the partitions to separate files, because otherwise the partitions that aren't at the beginning of the file will be hard to use. If you really want the three partitions in the same file, you can concatenate them:

```
cat /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sda3 >newImage.image
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easy quick answer is :

```
dd skip=2048 count=132552703 status=progress if=/dev/sda of=./newImage.image
```

fdisk -l by default returns partitions size in sectors of 512 bytes per sector

you can confirm that in the fdisk output it should show something like this :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256 GiB, 274877906944 bytes, 536870912 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

dd also uses 512 bytes as the default value for the switches "bs", "cbs", "ibs" and "obs"

```
  bs=BYTES        read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512);
                  overrides ibs and obs
  cbs=BYTES       convert BYTES bytes at a time
  conv=CONVS      convert the file as per the comma separated symbol list
  count=N         copy only N input blocks
  ibs=BYTES       read up to BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)
  if=FILE         read from FILE instead of stdin
  iflag=FLAGS     read as per the comma separated symbol list
  obs=BYTES       write BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)
  of=FILE         write to FILE instead of stdout
  oflag=FLAGS     write as per the comma separated symbol list
  seek=N          skip N obs-sized blocks at start of output
  skip=N          skip N ibs-sized blocks at start of input
  status=LEVEL    The LEVEL of information to print to stderr;
                  'none' suppresses everything but error messages,
                  'noxfer' suppresses the final transfer statistics,
                  'progress' shows periodic transfer statistics
```

to confirm that you can use dd itself to create a one block file like this :

dd if=/dev/urandom of=test count=1

The file size should be 512 bytes

so all you have to do to create an image of a partition or group of partitions
is to get the number of sectors for the start of the partition or first partition
from the output of fdisk and use it as the value of the dd parameter "skip" and then the number of sectors for the End of the partition or last partition and set it as the value for the dd parameter "count".

If there is a block size difference between fdisk and dd you can always specify the block size in dd using the parameter "bs" to make sure the block size matches between fdisk output and what dd is going to use.