# Enlarge a filesystem image

Tags: disk-image

I was doing `dpkg --configure -a` in my Debian wheezy.
And got this error:

```
dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: failed to write status record about `libcairo2' to `/var/lib/dpkg/status': No space left on device
```

I am chrooted into a `.img` file. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "chrooted into a .img file"?

Comment: please include the output of `df -h` command and yes what @StephenKitt asked too!

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin Thank you for responding. Df -h gets me / is 100% of it used. StephenKitt I have an image that I usr to chroot into. I mean, with losetup i mounted it and chrooted into it. Thank you both im trying the answer beneath atm though

Comment: Btw @JohnnyBoy there's a convenient shortcut `mount -oloop file /path` that does the losetup bit for you automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this correctly you need to:

1. First expand the *`.img`* file.
2. Next expand the filesystem within.

The *best* way to do the first thing is with `dd`. For whatever reason some people attribute a kind of mystery to the way `dd` works, but there really is none. For example, to append a *hole* to the end of your *`.img`* file:

```
dd bs=1kx1k seek=100 of=.img </dev/null
```

On any POSIX system that will *truncate* the file to 100MiBs. On a GNU system the `1kx1k` bit can be shortened to just `M`. `dd` seeks 100MiBs into the file, encounters EOF on its first read, and closes the file. It is a single action, and requires no reads *(beyond the first empty one)* or writes - it's very nearly atomic.

If the file was 50MiBs before, it will now be allocated 50MiBs more. If the file was 150MiBs before, that will chop the last 50MiBs off the tail. On a filesystem which understands *sparse* files, the appended file *hole* will use no disk-space, really, and will only use what is necessary as you fill it.

Other ways to do the same on some systems:

```
fallocate -l100M .img
truncate -s100M .img
```

...both of those commands will do the exact same thing `dd` will. I recommend `dd` because neither of those tools is portable where `dd`'s behavior is [POSIX-spec'd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html), and once you learn how to use the *disk-destroyer* properly, no disk will ever again *dare* to stand in your way.

If you are merely adding to your *`.img`* you can do the above thing whether or not it is mounted *(though if you were to take some of a mounted **`.img`** away it may not work as expected)*, but you will very likely need to `umount`*`.img`* first to resize its constituent filesystem anyway, and so might as well. You do not need to `-d`estroy the loop device, though.

How you handle the second thing depends on whether *`.img`* is partitioned or not. If it is not, as I guess is the case based on your comments elsewhere, then you'll only need to address the fs by its type. For an `ext[234]` *`.img`* file you should use `resize2fs` and be done with it. For others you'll want to look at the relevant user-space tools and their `man` pages.

If *`.img`* is partitioned it can be more complicated. In such cases how you handle the situation will depend on what kind of partition table is used *(such as GPT vs MBR vs hybrid-MBR)*, whether it is the *last* partition in the file's partition table and much else. I hesitate to venture any specifics here without more information: if you require advice on how to handle a partitioned *`.img`* please let me know with some more details and I will offer what I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However dd bs=1M count=500 >> .img works too. Just saying. Great answer

Comment: @Johnnyboy - Ok... but what is the input there?

Comment: @JohnnyBoy - and anyway, while it will work, you actually will have to copy something in that case. That means you need to 500 reads/writes. If you just `seek`, though, you only have to do 1.

Comment: Both are useful.  The `seek` / `truncate` method creates a "sparse file", where the space is not allocated until content is written to it.  The result may become more fragmented on-disk as a result.

Comment: Nice, I see the seek method doesn't require `conv=notrunc` (but there's still the possibility to botch it if you get the size too small, in the same way as `truncate`).  The manpage says dd sets the size it truncates to to the value of the seek argument.

Comment: @sourcejedi - yes, kind of. *[`seek=n`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html)
Skip n blocks **(using the specified output block size)** from the beginning of the output file before copying. On non-seekable files, existing blocks shall be read and space from the current end-of-file to the specified offset, if any, filled with null bytes; on seekable files, the implementation shall seek to the specified offset or read the blocks as described for non-seekable files.* So the `of` output-file is set to *at least* the size of `$((seek*obs))`.

Comment: @sourcejedi - it is fun, too. `seq 20 >nums; seq 20 | (</dev/null dd bs=20 seek=1; cat) 1<>nums; cat nums` - try it. You can achieve the same purpose with `<>` as you might with `conv=notrunc`. Some other `dd` stuff: a [`dd` ring-buffer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217109/52934) and a [hidden partition](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216591/52934).

Comment: Wow, great explanation!

Answer (score 7):

If the chroot filesystem is full, you can enlarge the image file.

E.g. using `dd conv=notrunc oflag=append bs=1M count=X of=file.img`.  Be very, very careful :).  It is strongly recommended to unmount the chroot and backup the .img file first, if you can.

Then resize the filesystem, so it can use the extra space.  For an ext4 filesystem the command would be `resize2fs`.  The manpage suggests you'll have to run that last command on a loop device, not the file:

```
# losetup -f file.img
# losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /home/alan/file.img
# resize2fs /dev/loop0
...
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Command will be different for different filesystems, e.g. `btrfs filesystem resize /dev/loop0 max`, or `xfs_growfs /test.img/is/mounted/here`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I get "invalid conversion append" after the dd command and I resize2fs says the "filesystem is already 183105 (4k) bytes long. Nothing to do! "

Comment: @JohnnyBoy Don't bother with `dd`, it's hard to use and harder to use reliably. Just use something like `truncate -s 10G foo.img` where 10G is the new size you want for the image (larger than the current size!). Do that with the image unmounted. Then resize the filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, fixed.  `truncate` works too, and there is a difference in the result w.r.t possible performance (commented on the other answer).

Comment: I got this error: resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/loop6
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: @Felipe Maybe the `dd` command you used was wrong, and it won't mount anymore? If it does mount, are you sure it's an ext4 filesystem? What does `blkid` or `file` / `file -s` think about it?

Comment: It was a qcow2 image (instead raw), that's why it didn't work. I was able to expand following this tutorial: https://www.cyberithub.com/resize-qcow2-image-with-virt-resize-kvm-tools/